# Angular:add dynamic class

Tags: angular, css, primeng

I have a json that will return me border color, which is to be applied to a span. JSON is
    File = [
     {
      'borderColor':'red'
     }
    ]

How to apply class dynamically?

My html is, simple

```
<div *ngFor="let file of File">
 <span dynamicClassComesHere></span>
```

Comment: is that worked for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let file of File">
 <span [style.border-color]="file.borderColor"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be -

```
 <span [ngClass]='dynamicClass'></span>
```

## [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfjaut?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

> Apart from this there are various ways to do so as per **official docs**

```
<some-element [ngClass]="'first second'">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="['first', 'second']">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="stringExp|arrayExp|objExp">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>
```

[Read more about ngClass here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#usage-notes)

Comment: This did not worked in my case, the comment below worked

Comment: @Anna have you checked my working example? and comment below is adding style dynamically not class. I think question is about adding class dynamically

Comment: Yes i check you working ex, same code did not work in my workspace

Comment: @Anna then most probably error is somewhere else from your code, please check that !

Answer (score 0):

as its just single style use `ngStyle` like this

```
const style = {'borderColor':'red'};//ts file 
<span [ngStyle]="style"></span >
<span [ngStyle]="{'borderColor':getBorderColor()}"></span >
```

in your case

```
<div *ngFor="let file of File">
 <span [ngStyle]="JSON.stringify(file)"></span>
```

or can be like this

```
    <span [style.borderColor]="getBorderColor()">
    getBorderColor() {
     style =  JSON.parse(`{ 'borderColor':'red' }`);
     return style.borderColor;
   }
```

in your case

```
<div *ngFor="let file of File">
 <span [style.borderColor]="file.borderColor"></span>
```